# Is there a way to search a list in python by converting it to a numpy matrix fast?

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy

I'm trying to search a python 2D array by looping over the rows of the array and checking if values inside match a condition. An example is here:

```
def searchList(list, v0, v1, v2, v3):
 for r in range(len(list)):
    if (list[r][0] == v0) & (list[r][1] == v1) & (list[r][2] == v2) & (list[r][3] == v3):
        return r

 return None
```

This, however, is quite slow in python compared to other languages.

Now the main problem is that this list is dynamically growing, and could have 1000 or more rows.

When I went online to search how to make this faster I found moving the list to a numpy matrix and using `np.where()` could do this.

```
def searchList(list, v0, v1, v2, v3):
    tmpQ = np.array(list)
    locList = np.where((tmpQ[:,0] == v0) & (tmpQ[:,1] == v1) & (tmpQ[:,2] == v2) & (tmpQ[:,3] == v3))
    if locList[0].size == 0:
        return None
    else:
        return locList[0][0]
```

Now the problem is that converting the python 2D array into a numpy matrix is that this operation takes a lot of time as well.

My other option is to get rid of the python 2D array and only using numpy matrix, this however also doesn't work as the matrix keeps growing the operation of concatenation takes a long time.

Is there any way to do this fast?

I know what is causing taking the most time by using cProfile and running the code.

Comment: You shouldn't shadow the Python built-in `list` with your variable name.

Comment: I don't imagine it's any faster but try - `for row in list: if [v0, v1, v2, v3] == row[:4]: ...`.

Comment: Are all elements in your list have the same length?

Comment: `np.all(tmpQ==np.array([v0,v1,v2,v3]), axis=1)`, if I got it right, should make the `where` conditional shorter (but not necessarily faster).

Comment: If `list` was a `set` of 4 element tuples, the test would be faster.  Or better a dictionary, with tuple as key, and value being a row list.

Answer (score 0):

it depend on your data shape, you can try this:

```
def searchList(mylist, v0, v1, v2, v3):
    try:
        row_num = mylist.index([v0, v1, v2, v3])
    except ValueError:
        return None
    return row_num 


m = [[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [3,2,8,7], [1,3,6,9]]
print(searchList(m, 3, 2, 8, 7))
```

output:

```
2
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are searching a list for 4 consecutive entries.
For example, you might wish to find the numbers `1, 5, 6,` and `7` appearing adjacent to each-other in the list.

That is called a "[single pattern string matching algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String-searching_algorithm#Single-pattern_algorithms)"

Your code is slow because you have implemented the brute-force solution to the problem.
The brute-force algorithm requires time proportional to `n*m`, where `n` is the length of your list and `m` is the length of your contiguous sub-list (m = 4 for your example).

Rather than write the code yourself (reinvent the wheel), I recommend that you use someone else's code. I haven't tried the following, but it looks to be a python implementation of the [Knuthe-Morris-Pratt Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) :

[python implementation on github](https://gist.github.com/m00nlight/daa6786cc503fde12a77)